# Set People picker field with sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell-script

Is it possible to set a People picker field with SharePoint Group using powershell script ?.
Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-values-using-powershell.html?m=1). This might help you.

Comment: Yes i saw this. This example is to Set the People picker field with user Collection. I want to just add SharePoint Group.

Comment: Thank you i will try

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to set a People picker field with SharePoint Group.

As an workaround:

Create an AD group with a list of users in your SharePoint group.

Add this AD group to SharePoint group.

You can choose that AD group from people picker.

Comment: For example in the Task list "Assigned To" People picker field, we can assign a SharePoint Group when we create a new Task item ?.